# Is it possible to perform user count / cardinality with logical relationship in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, count, cardinality

I have documents of Users with the following format:

```
{
    userId: "<userId>",
    userAttributes: [
        "<Attribute1>",
        "<Attribute2>",
        ...
        "<AttributeN>"
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to get the number of unique users that answer a logic statement, for example ***How many users have attribute1 AND attribute2 OR attribute3?***

I've read about the cardinality function in [cardinality-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) but it seems to work for a single value, lacking the logic abilities of "AND" and "OR".

Note that I have around 1,000,000,000 documents and I need the results as fast as possible, this why I was looking at the cardinality estimation.

Comment: Cardinality aggregation looks like the obvious solution. Have you tried it? Does it do what you want? I'm not sure I fully understand your post...

Comment: @AndreiStefan - It works for a single attribute very good. but I didn't find a way to include "AND" and "OR" logic to it. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or is it just not supported.

Comment: Ok, that's different from what you initially asked. Can you update your post with the mapping for `userAttributes` and the query you attempted and couldn't make it work?>

Answer (score 1):

What about this attempt, considering the `userAttributes` as a simple array of `string`s (analyzed in my case, but single lowercase terms):

```
POST /users/user/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"userId":123,"userAttributes":["xxx","yyy","zzz"]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"userId":234,"userAttributes":["xxx","yyy","aaa"]}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"userId":345,"userAttributes":["xxx","yyy","bbb"]}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"userId":456,"userAttributes":["xxx","ccc","zzz"]}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"userId":567,"userAttributes":["xxx","ddd","ooo"]}

GET /users/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "userAttributes:(((xxx AND yyy) NOT zzz) OR ooo)"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_ids": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "userId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives the following:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.16471066,
        "_source": {
           "userAttributes": [
              "xxx",
              "yyy",
              "aaa"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.04318809,
        "_source": {
           "userAttributes": [
              "xxx",
              "yyy",
              "bbb"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.021594046,
        "_source": {
           "userAttributes": [
              "xxx",
              "ddd",
              "ooo"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```